# Lightning component with the dropdown inputSelect

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, ui-inputselect

I am creating a lightning component with the dropdown which gets the value dynamically from the controller, which is basically the lightning component shows a dropdown with the list of Recordtype that users has access to. I am getting the dropdown populated with values working
[image]

The issue is if the first element is the record type without doing anything if I hit next I get the error
`Attempt to de-reference a null object`

[image]

But if I change the element in the drop down list and hit next it works as expected. How can I handle if the first element is the desired record type. The code for the inputSelect is like below

```
        <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectid">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfRecordType}" var="opportunity">                            
                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!opportunity}" label="{!opportunity}"  />
                </aura:iteration>
            </ui:inputSelect>
```

And the controller method which gets the values

```
@AuraEnabled        
public static List<String> fetchRecordTypeValues(){
    List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordtypes = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();    
    recordtypemap = new Map<Id, String>();
    for(RecordTypeInfo rt : recordtypes){
        if( rt.isAvailable() && rt.getName() != 'Master')
            recordtypemap.put(rt.getRecordTypeId(), rt.getName());
    }        
    return recordtypemap.values();
}
```

Or how can I add like None or something to the list. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `ui` elements should not be used. Use `lightning:select` instead. Aside from that, this is an Apex error, so you need to update your code to allow a null value.

Comment: @sfdcfox I added in question the method which I use to fetch the record types that can be used in the dropdown. Do you ask me to add to the returned list? Can you please give me an example of how I can use lightning:select  here

Comment: @user81642 - I guess, you did not set the default/selected value in JS controller, that is why on load it is not working properly and like sfdcfox suggested, prefer to use lightning:select (since ui namespace is deprecated).